# Resize MKAnnotationView with MKZoomScale - Swift 2.0

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit, mkannotation, mkoverlay

I'm trying to make an annotation that will be resizable

I have a custom annotation that I created

```
class MapAnnotation: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var image: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "image")

    init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {
        self.coordinate = coordinate
    }
}
```

and annotationView that includes the image.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
    if let annotation = annotation as? MapAnnotation {
        var pin = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier("myCustomAnnotation")
        if pin == nil {
            pin = MKAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: "myCustomAnnotation")
        }
        pin!.image = annotation.image
        return pin
    }
    return nil
}
```

And when I'm resizing the mapView I want that the MKAnnotationView will be resized as well.

I know that MKOverlayRenderer has the `drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext)` function that includes the zoomScale: MKZoomScale parameter.

Moreover I saw this solution:

```
let zoomScale: MKZoomScale = mapView.bounds.size.width /
        CGFloat(mapView.visibleMapRect.size.width)
```

But I want the access to the `MKZoomScale` in the `drawMapRect` function and not the customize way.

That means that I need to make an MKOverlayRenderer instead of MKAnnotationView which I don't want to, Because MKOverlay is drawing on the map and I want to make an annotationView, that isn't drawn on the map.

After that I'll have the MKZoomScale I want to resize the annotationViews between MKZoomScale 1 to 0.25 and if the MKZoomScale is lower than 0.25 I want the annotationViews will disappear.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the "zoom" amount from the span on the mapView's region var:

```
mapView.region.span
```

Then, in your `viewForAnnotation` function, you can do some math to scale the annotation, or have the annotation do some kind of function on itself to display larger.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
<pin init methods>
let averageSpan = mapView.region.span.x * mapView.region.span.x * 0.5
let pinScale = someFunctionToReturnScaleBasedOnAverageSpan(averageSpan)
pin.scaleSelf(pinScale)
return pin
```

}

I don't remember off the top of my head, but if `viewForAnnotation` doesn't get called when the map updates its span, you need to some kind of update function that removes and adds annotations.

It would, however, be easier to use an MKOverlay.

Comment: Is just that MKZoomScale in the function 
`drawMapRect(mapRect: MKMapRect, zoomScale: MKZoomScale, inContext context: CGContext)`
giving you a default zoomScale that I want to use.
If I wanted to use MKCoordinateSpan I would already use it.
You can try use the function `drawMapRect` and print the `zoomScale`, and by that you can see what I'm talking about.